# How can I apply graph neural networks with different number of nodes in each instance for image classification?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, classification, graph-neural-network

I have a dataset with images of different sizes and I would like to maintain all the information of the images. I would like to test graph neural networks for doing that.

Is it possible to apply GNN with graphs with different numbers of nodes for image classification?

Every GNN can be applied for this? If this is not the case, which kind of neural network should I use?

Is there any recommended example of code for doing this?